# Image pre-processing in OCR

Tags: preprocessor, ocr

Our project is all about OCR and base on my research, before performing the character recognition it will go through on pre-processing stage. I know we can use openCV for that but we can't use it base on our rules.

My question is, can someone tells me the step-by-step of pre processing and the best method/algorithm to use.

like what I know,

1.YUVluminace

2.greyscale

3.otsu thresholding

4.Binarization

5.Hough transform

Original Image> YUVluminace> greyscale what's next??

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In some of my older blog posts, I addressed some parts of your questions:

Binarization on various image qualities from mobile cameras:
http://www.ocr-it.com/guide-to-better-mobile-images-from-cell-phone-camera-for-higher-quality-ocr

Image pre-rpocessing and segmentation for better OCR:
http://www.ocr-it.com/user-scenario-process-digital-camera-pictures-and-ocr-to-extract-specific-numbers

In reality, there is no step-by-step, per my experience.  You could use original image for OCR if you wanted to, with means no pre-processing is nessesary.  Yes, pre-processing will help, but it depends on the source and type of your images (which you did not specify).  For example, a typical office document scanned on a professional scanner with Kofax VRS requires no pre-processing before OCR.  Mobile camera image requires a lot of pre-processing.  Picture from a parking garage camera will require a lot of pre-processing, but different steps and algorithms from mobile camera picture.

I think decide what is the next major limiting factor in your images, pre-process against it, then look for the next correctable issue.